# long wrapped flex item pushing others down

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got 3 divs of different lengths in a flex box. Each div is 47% width. I am using flex wrap to have them wrap. The longest div is second in the order and pushes the third div all the way down to where it ends. Is there anyway to have the third div come right up under the first div.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EbwPeW)

HTML

```
<div class="flex-box">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-box{
  display: flex;
  background: black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 500px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;

}
.flex-item{
  width: 47%;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Experiment with the `.flex-item{width: 47%;}` or add `.flex-item{margin-right: 3%;}`.

Answer (score 0):

For arranging items both vertically and horizontally with a single container, use `grid` rather than `flex` -- that's what it's for!

Here's the CSS for a `grid` solution, with the HTML unchanged:

```
.flex-box{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 47% 47%;
  grid-template-rows: 78px auto;
  background: black;
  width: 500px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: start;

}
.flex-item{
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.flex-item:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-row-start: span 2;
}
```

You may want to change/add classes in the HTML to avoid fiddling with `nth-of-type`.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the `class="flex-item"` in the below manner.

```
<div class="flex-item"></div>
<div class="flex-item"></div>
<div class="flex-item"></div> //Longest div container
```

And then just give `flex-direction:column` to the container.
and not to forget to give `max-height:(Anything less than your container height)` to your container.

---

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 500px;
  max-height: 520px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 47%;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-item">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```